# Nested List using indexing and slicing

Tags: python-3.x, program-slicing

How do I slice or index this list in order to get the answer below? I've tried doing multiple methods of slicing and nothing has worked for me.

```
L = [0, [], [1,2,3,4], [[5],[6,7]], [8,9,10]]
newL = [L[0],L[2][1],L[2][2],L[3][0]]
```

Answer:  [0, 2, 3, [5 ,6], 8, 10]

newL is what I have so far, but I can't seem to get the [6,7] split in the nested list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We start with:

```
L = [0, [], [1, 2, 3, 4], [[5], [6, 7]], [8, 9, 10]]
```

We want:

```
[0, 2, 3, [5, 6], 8, 10]
```

Let's start from the farthest inside.  We need `[5, 6]`.  These are both *buried*:

```
>>> L[3][0][0]
5
>>> L[3][1][0]
6
>>> [L[3][0][0], L[3][1][0]]
[5, 6]
```

One layer farther out we need `2, 3`:

```
>>> L[2][1]
2
>>> L[2][2]
3
```

Now put it together:

```
>>> [L[0], L[2][1], L[2][2], [L[3][0][0], L[3][1][0]], L[4][0], L[4][2]]
[0, 2, 3, [5, 6], 8, 10]
```